# How do I randomize a SQL query in MS Access to pull a random entry?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a list of locations in a table. I want a query to pull a random location each time it is called. The query seems to work just fine, but if I close and reopen the database, it gives the same locations in the same order. How do I get the query to give me random locations without showing a pattern?

Right now the query is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Location
FROM tblLocations
ORDER BY RND(index);
```

If I remove the `index` portion, the query returns a list of locations at random, but doesn't return just one.

Comment: hint: is index a unique sequence key?

Comment: It is unique, at least the box is checked in the table.